# Dropdown menu creation

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using joomla and helix ultimate 2 template, I'm trying to create a dropdown menu to the user module, in order not to lose the changes I created a "custom.js" file but I couldn't find a code that worked. following the html code by inspecting the browser

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClass("sp-profile-dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.sp.sign-in')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("sp-dropdown-item");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.sp-profile-wrapper .sp-profile-dropdown {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px !important;
    list-style: none !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100px;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    display: none !important;
```

```html
<div class="d-none d-lg-flex header-modules align-items-center">
                            
                                                            <div class="sp-module">
<div class="sp-profile-wrapper">
<a href="#" class="sp-sign-in"><i class="fas fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="user-text d-none d-xl-inline-block"> Anthony Marra</span> <i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<ul class="sp-profile-dropdown">
    <li class="sp-profile-dropdown-item">
        <a href="/il-tuo-profilo/profile.html">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sp-profile-dropdown-item">
        <a href="/loggg.html?layout=logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>                                                  </div>
```

What code could I use to create a dropwdown?

Comment: The snippet is incomplete without the javascript, and whatever else may be necessary to have a minimal reproducible example. Please add the other missing items. (and no need to have two blocks of the same html, the first block should be removed) ... In your own website with everything present, ensure to check the browser's console tab to ensure that you don't have any javascript errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest,
I have updated the snippet

Comment: If you are a Joomla user or Joomla developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.